# zonal histogram fails to create output table when looping

Tags: arcgis-10.0, python, raster, arcgis-10.1, python-2.7

Using python I'm having problems when trying to attempt a FOR LOOP with the ZonalHistogram function of ArcGIS 10.1. It works fine if I use it only for one image but it gives me this error while for looping:

```
ExecuteError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
Create output table failed
Failed to execute (ZonalHistogram)
```

Here is my very simple script:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy.sa import *

arcpy.env.workspace = 'G:\\Chile_2012\\MODIS10A2.V005\\prova'

elev_ranges = 'G:\\Chile_2012\\MODIS10A2.V005\\DEM\\elev_ranges'
list = arcpy.ListRasters ()
out_dir = 'G:\\Chile_2012\\MODIS10A2.V005\\prova\\hypso\\'

arcpy.CheckOutExtension ('Spatial')

for raster in list:
    ZonalHistogram (raster, 'Value', elev_ranges, out_dir+ raster+ '.dbf')
```

Comment: Ok I found out that this is a problem of the service pack (http://downloads2.esri.com/support/downloads/other_/185410.0_SP5_Announcement.pdf). I then tried to save it as an in_memory object without specifying any name as suggested in the link above and it worked, but then how could I make this files permanent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

The problem was assigning a name to the output table (as specified in the "SP5 announcement" of ESRI). I created "in_memory" files by appending an 'in_memory' string at the end of the pathname, and made a list on the temporary tables created in this way to merge them with the "Merge" tool. Tyhen I deleted all the temporary files by using the "arcpy.Delete_management ('in_memory')" tool and it worked fine. Hope this could help someone in the future. Here is the link with some bugs of ESRI.
http://downloads2.esri.com/support/downloads/other_/185410.0_SP5_Announcement.pdf

Comment: Anyway, it doesn't work properly, it gives a strange result that has nothing to do with the result coming from a single application of the Zonal tool. Something doesn't work when looping...

Answer (score 0):

I have a vector with 23k polygons, and a raster with 8 class. Result: how many classes I have in each polygon?

This code is very simple and working for me.

```
from rasterstats import zonal_stats
stats = zonal_stats('myvector.shp','myraster.tif',categorical=True)
print(stats)
#OUT
{0: 2, 1: 1, 2: 31, 3: 2, 4: 528, 7: 61}
```