# Zonal histogram completed but no output created

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst, histogram, frequency

I am trying to obtain zonal histogram data for about 10 000 statistical sectors in Belgium.
So I have a shapefile containing these polygons. 
I also have a value raster which has been reclassified : it contains integer values from 1 to 5. 
When I run zonal histogram, the tool runs (for a little more than 1 hour) and then displays "Completed". The result window confirms that the Output was created, however, I can't display it. If I go looking for it manually, it's also absent.

Is there a solution to this ? 
I would like to obtain a table with the refid of each zone and a column with the counts of pixels of value 1, a second column counting the pixels with value 2, etc.

[image: Result Window]

Answer (score 1):

The tool cannot handle more than 255 zones (as the zones are as columns in the output). The zonal feature layer has to be cut in pieces of maximum 255 zones.

Answer (score 0):

I have a vector with 23k polygons, and a raster with 8 class. Result: how many classes I have in each polygon?

https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/306266/133755